# Beautiful Soup - find a tag within a tag with string? nth-child?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I'm having some trouble with the following HTML Scrape

```
 res =   <div class="gunDetails">
    <h4>Specifications</h4>
    <ul class="features">
        <li><label>Make:</label><span itemprop="brand">Gamo</span></li>
        <li><label>Model:</label><span itemprop="model">Coyote Black Tactical</span></li>
        <li><label>Licence:</label><span>No Licence</span></li>
        <li><label>Orient.:</label><span>Ambidextrous</span></li>
        <li><label>Scope:</label><span>Unknown&nbsp;3-9x32</span></li>
        <li><label>Origin:</label><span>Spanish</span></li>
        <li><label>Cased:</label><span>Other</span></li>
        <li><label>Trigger:</label><span>1</span></li>
        <li><label>Condition:</label><span itemprop="itemCondition">Used</span></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
```

I'm trying to get the  text into its own seperate variable so i can export it to a CSV with my own headers.

Any time i do it i can get all of them in a string, or none at all.

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(res, 'html.parser')
gun_details = soup.select_one('div.gunDetails')
for tag in gun_details or []:
  for tag in gun_details.select("li"):
   for tag in gun_details.select('span'):
      print(tag.text)
```

Output

```
Gamo
Coyote Black Tactical
No License
Ambidextrous
Unknown 3-9x32
Spanish
Other
1
Used
```

Is there anyway in which i could create a variable for each label text?
something like?

```
gun_make = gun_details.findAll('label', String="Make:")
print(gun_make).text
```

This is the Full Code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import csv

all_links=[]
labels = []
spans = []
url="https://www.guntrader.uk/dealers/redcar/spencers-sporting-guns/guns?page={}"

for page in range(1,3):
  res=requests.get(url.format(page)).text
  soup=BeautifulSoup(res,'html.parser')
  for link in soup.select('a[href*="/dealers/redcar/spencers-sporting-guns/guns/shotguns"]'):
  all_links.append("https://www.guntrader.uk" + link['href'])


print(len(all_links))
for a_link in all_links:
  res = requests.get(a_link).text
  soup = BeautifulSoup(res, 'html.parser')
  gun_details = soup.select('div.gunDetails')
  for l in gun_details.select('label'):
   labels.append(l.text.replace(':',''))
  for s in gun_details.select('span'):
   spans.append(s.text)

my_dict = dict(zip(labels, spans))
with open('gundealer.csv','w') as csvfile:
 writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames=None)
 for key in mydict.keys():
   csvfile.write(f"{key},{my_dict[key]}\n")
```

This section seems to work on its own OK giving the correct(ish) output:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

response = request.get('guntrader.uk/guns/air-rifles/gamo/pre-charged-pneumatic/22/coyote-black-tactical-190920182249936')

soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')
gun_details = soup.select_one('div.gunDetails')
gun_make = gun_details.select_one('li:nth-child(1)')
print (gun_make.text)
```

With the output:

```
Make: Gamo
```

But I dont know what im doing to mess up the initial response from the loop to not allow the above snippet not to work

Comment: What is it you want for output?

Comment: Really just want to be able to identify each <label> as 1 single item and to print its <span> text.  I was even wondering could i some how get the whole <li> and split it at the make: to only give me the span output

Comment: I'm not sure what exactly you are looking for, but you could create a dictionary with key/value pairs like `'Make:': 'Gamo', 'Model:': 'Coyote Black Tactical'`, etc.

Comment: I updated it there with my full code to see if anyone can see where im going wrong

Comment: It's still not clear; can post the exact expected output?

Comment: @JackFleeting long and short im trying to grab the text found within the Span of each li and put that text into a csv

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's try this:

```
res =  """ <div class="gunDetails">
    <h4>Specifications</h4>
    <ul class="features">
        <li><label>Make:</label><span itemprop="brand">Gamo</span></li>
        <li><label>Model:</label><span itemprop="model">Coyote Black Tactical</span></li>
        <li><label>Licence:</label><span>No Licence</span></li>
        <li><label>Orient.:</label><span>Ambidextrous</span></li>
        <li><label>Scope:</label><span>Unknown&nbsp;3-9x32</span></li>
        <li><label>Origin:</label><span>Spanish</span></li>
        <li><label>Cased:</label><span>Other</span></li>
        <li><label>Trigger:</label><span>1</span></li>
        <li><label>Condition:</label><span itemprop="itemCondition">Used</span></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
""

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import csv

labels = []
spans = []
soup = bs(res, 'html.parser')
gun_details = soup.select_one('div.gunDetails')
for l in gun_details.select('label'):
    labels.append(l.text.replace(':',''))
for s in gun_details.select('span'):
    spans.append(s.text)

my_dict = dict(zip(labels, spans))
with open('mycsvfile.csv','w') as csvfile:
        writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames=None)
        for key in my_dict.keys():
            csvfile.write(f"{key},{my_dict[key]}\n")
```

Output:

```
Make    Gamo
Model   Coyote Black Tactical
Licence No Licence
Orient. Ambidextrous
Scope   Unknown 3-9x32
Origin  Spanish
Cased   Other
Trigger 1
Condition   Used
```

Comment: Hi Jack,  Thanks for that.  Works in that scenario the best.  one issue im having is bringing this into my code above regarding the loop in the full script for page in rage(1,3)......    keep getting the error 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'select'

Comment: i think its how im calling the links into the for loop.  ill edit the full script again to show the current script with your update to it included

Comment: You have 24 links in there; I used a random selection of these links and didn't get the error. Try to find the exact link where the error occurred.

Comment: Would it just be one / a few links which could be causing the issue?

Comment: Yes, I tried a random 5 links and no problem. I guess there's one that causes the problem.

Comment: im breaking it down with prints to see where the error originates.  seems to be something to do with the for l in gun_details.select('label'):  - getting a new error 'list' object has no attribute 'select'

Comment: @AndrewGlass - So, did you find the problematic url?

Comment: yeah found it and works now.  my issue now is i've around 20 items i want to add to the CSV but its constantly just adding the one record into the csv.  You mind having a look?

Comment: @AndrewGlass - Sure, but you'll have to post it as a separate question (SO policy) and I'll take a look. And, if you're done with this one, you should accept its answer (if acceptable).

Comment: Aye good man appriciate it.  Yeah that answer is correct in the context provided so will accept the answer now. the link > https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58048469/beautiful-soup-results-to-csv-for-all-items-in-lists