# Beautiful Soup - Results to CSV for all items in lists

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-requests

The below snippet "works" but is only outputting the first record to the CSV.  I'm trying to get it to output the same output, but for each gun in the list of gun urls in the all_links list.

Any modification i've made to it with prints for the output (just to see it working) prints the same result

or if i make a gun_details list and try to print it, get the same one item output.

How would i go about printing all the gun_details labels and spans into a CSV?

```py
import csv
import urllib.request

import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

all_links = []


url = "https://www.guntrader.uk/dealers/minsterley/minsterley-ranges/guns?page={}"
for page in range(1, 3):
    res = requests.get(url).text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(res, "html.parser")
    for link in soup.select(
        'a[href*="dealers/minsterley/minsterley-ranges/guns/shotguns/"]'
    ):
        all_links.append("https://www.guntrader.uk" + link["href"])

for a_link in all_links:

    gun_label = []
    gun_span = []

    res = urllib.request.urlopen(a_link)
    # res = requests.get(a_link)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(res, "html.parser")
    for gun_details in soup.select("div.gunDetails"):
        for l in gun_details.select("label"):
            gun_label.append(l.text.replace(":", ""))
        for s in gun_details.select("span"):
            gun_span.append(s.text)

my_dict = dict(zip(gun_label, gun_span))
with open("mycsvfile.csv", "w") as csvfile:
    writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames=None)
    for key in my_dict.keys():
        csvfile.write(f"{key},{my_dict[key]}\n")
```

Comment: Well, let's try this first: see what happens if you change `open('mycsvfile.csv', 'w')` to `open('mycsvfile.csv', 'a')`?

Comment: same result. - previously put that its putting it in 3 times, but that was me not deleting the previous csv before running it again *doh*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try running the middle section this way:

```
for a_link in all_links:
    gun_label = []
    gun_span = []

    res = requests.get(a_link)
    soup = bs(res.content, 'html.parser') #note it's 'res.content', not just 'res'
    for gun_details in soup.select('div.gunDetails'):
        for l in gun_details.select('label'):
            gun_label.append(l.text.replace(':',''))
    for s in gun_details.select('span'):
        gun_span.append(s.text)

    #this block is now indented differently - it's INSIDE the 'for' loop
    my_dict = dict(zip(gun_label, gun_span))
    with open('mycsvfile.csv', 'a') as csvfile:
        writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames=None)
        for key in my_dict.keys():
            csvfile.write(f"{key},{my_dict[key]}\n")
```

Comment: hahaha awh man that actually annoys me that i didnt cop onto that! nicely spotted!